# grep a file and pipe the output to sed and store sed output in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, grep, sed

Contents of `source.txt`:

```
gold  green white black blue
yellow magenta brown 
tram kilo charlie tango
```

Hi everyone! I need to solve a mystery.

I'm trying to run a small script to grep a file `source.txt`, pipe `grep` output to `sed` replace a  string and store that line in a new file `pol.txt`

```
grep -l "gold" source.txt | xargs sed  's/green/red/' >  pol.txt
```

Instead of having the only that line stored in `pol.txt`:

```
gold  red white black blue
```

I have the entire file itself with the string I replaced

```
gold  red white black blue
yellow magenta brown 
tram kilo charlie tango
```

When I remove the  option `-l` from grep command I have this and of course nothing in pol.txt

```
sed: can't read gold: No such file or directory
sed: can't read green: No such file or directory
sed: can't read white: No such file or directory
sed: can't read black: No such file or directory
sed: can't read blue: No such file or directory
```

`grep` is needed as a tester and unfortunately " if " is not an option.

Comment: As John1234’s answer shows, you hardly ever need to use `grep` and `sed` together — `sed` by itself can probably do anything that the two programs can do together.  If you have a problem where you have multiple input files and you need to process only the ones that contain “gold”, you should probably explain that; otherwise, people who are trying to answer your question have one hand tied behind their back.  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.)  As Satya Mishra explains, `grep -l "gold" source.txt` will output `source.txt`  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  if the file contains the word “gold” (and nothing if it doesn’t).  If the only thing that you’re writing into your pipe is the `source.txt` filename, there’s no way the process on the right side of the pipe can know that you want it to process only the *lines* that contain “gold” unless you build that into the command (as John demonstrates). (His command can be simplified a little, to `sed -n '/gold/s/green/red/p' source.txt`.  And, if you can write `sed 's/green/red/'`, is this really so “frightening” that “it will be a pain” to maintain?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select any line containing `gold` from source.txt and replace the first occurrence of `green` with `red`:

```
$ sed  -n '/gold/{s/green/red/; p}' source.txt 
gold  red white black blue
```

To save that in a file:

```
sed  -n '/gold/{s/green/red/; p}' source.txt  >pol.txt
```

#### How it works

- `-n` tells sed not to print lines unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/gold/` selects lines that match the regex `gold`.
- `s/green/red/` performs the substitution
- `p` prints.

#### Using awk

With the same logic:

```
$ awk '/gold/{gsub(/green/, "red"); print}' source.txt 
gold  red white black blue
```

#### Using grep

If we are forced, for reasons not yet explained, to use a grep pipeline, then try:

```
$ grep -l --null "gold" source.txt | xargs -0 sed  -n '/gold/s/green/red/p'
gold  red white black blue
```

Comment: thanks john for your input but, grep is needed. Grep will be use as tester before handing output to sed.

Comment: @Driven Why do you think that grep is needed as a tester?  sed is perfectly capable of doing the same test.  Unless you have some other requirement not yet explained?

Comment: I'm planning to automate the process with a for loop through several  files.

Comment: To process several files, there is no need for a `for` loop.  Sed can take multiple file names on one command line.  (If there are still more requirements, instead of revealing your goal piecemeal, you might as well just specify them all at once.)

Comment: @Driven I have added a version with a grep pipeline.

Comment: thanks, John the main reason is that I'm not really good with sed, in fact I always try to stay away from it. sed syntax is too frightening and I know that in a long run it will be a pain if I need to improve the script

Comment: @Driven In honor of that, I added an `awk` solution.  As with `sed`, many filenames can be placed on the `awk` command line.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -l "gold" source.txt` will output `source.txt` if the file contains the word gold
`xargs sed  's/green/red/'` will run `sed 's/green/red/' source.txt` and the final redirect saves the result in your output.

If I understand your intent correctly, you want the following command:

```
sed -n '/gold/s/green/red/p' source.txt > pol.txt
```

The `/gold/` selects lines matching `gold` and the `s` command does the replacement you want.